# Dependency 'io.quarkus:quarkus-quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq:' not found

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, messaging, quarkus

I am trying to implement RabbitMQ with Quarkus and in the Doc they said to use
`<dependency> <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId> <artifactId>quarkus-quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq</artifactId> </dependency>`
and in my project i cant find this dependency

Comment: What is Quarkus version ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a typo in dependency name (Quarkus is mentioned twice), try this :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-rabbitmq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```